# IE9 displaying distorted version of website

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

[This website](http://www.kiddlewinks.com.au/) displays fine in Chrome & Firefox, but displays as left-aligned in IE9, and the image gallery is skewed also.

I don't understand why IE9 would be showing such a different display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 3rd party web firm had altered the Opencart template to include a script element before the head element, which apparently puts IE into quirks mode.

Thanks to [Frankie on CodingForums.com](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=287491) for fixing this for me.

His post:

> By putting this before the doctype, you ordered IE into quirks mode:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  jQuery(".the-content").hide();
                  jQuery(".the-head").click(function()       {
                    jQuery(this).next(".the-content").slideToggle(500);
                  });
                });
</script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

> Put it inside the head. And you can delete the last line. You don't need that, and it sets off IE6.